# Who is the actress who plays the adorable girl who welcomes Sol into the suicide/euthanasia clinic?

Tags: identify-this-actor, soylent-green

When Sol goes to commit assisted suicide in Soylent Green, she greets him at the door of the Euthanesia clinic and welcomes him in with the following conversation:

> Girl: May I help you, Sir?
>
> Sol: It feels good.
>
> Girl: Yes, Sir, Won't you come in?

She's not credited in the film itself, or on IMDB or any other place I can find.

[image]

Full conversation, about 10 seconds into this clip:

Please don't paste a link to IMDB as she's not there. Also note, I'm not talking about the attendant who is inside the clinic.

I mean the girl in the white top who is at the door, seen in the picture.

Comment: Separate clips of the two lines are found here...  https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/32986b76-ae94-4aed-9306-ff395cf3b7f2

Comment: ...and here: https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/a6f7bfe1-1fa0-4222-9900-f20a6688676a

Comment: She must be one of the furniture girls, don't you think? http://prntscr.com/as3w7o

Comment: @GinoPane - it's not Erica Hagen and Beverly Gill is black so it can't be her. Cheri Howell's other credit is "Indian Girl" so it seems unlikely to be her either.

Comment: @GinoPane - It's not Leigh Taylor Young or Kathy Silva. http://s1173.photobucket.com/user/DogByte6/media/85215-17914_zps889cb134.jpg.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

She's indeed not credited on Soylent Green's IMDb page, but on actress **Diane Dye**'s IMDb [page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0245656/), there's the following tidbit from the message board:

> ***Cameo appearance uncredited in Soylent Green (1973)***
>   I went to school with Diane, and I just found out she was in Soylent Green in 1973. It's one of my favorite movies, and I had no idea that she had appeared in a scene. She's the lovely long-haired brunette opening the door for Edward G. Robinson's character into the "suicide center".

And looking up pictures of Diane, this one from *Emperor of the North* of the same year does look like the woman in your picture *[Warning: Wet Garments]*

> [image]

Comment: Oh, your'e so right! That is her! I am in awe of your knowledge!